# Is there a string operation similar to `+=` but adds to the front of the string?

Tags: c++, string, prepend

I know that `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y`. Is there an operation which is equivalent to `x = y + x`. For example, using this operation to combine `x`  and `y`, where `x` and `y` are `"1"` and `"2"`, would make `x` equal to `"21"`, not `"12"`?

What's the easiest way to achieve prepending a string in-place?

Comment: You may not overload operations for fundamental types. But you may declare a class that will simulate integers and for objects of this class you can overload an operation as you like. However you may not introduce new operators. You may overload operators that already exist in the language.

Comment: @NathanOliver I meant as strings!!! I will edit now.

Comment: @theo2003: Nothing in C++ prevents you from implementing your overloaded `x += y` as `x = y + x`. It is not a good practice, but you can just do it. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @AnT I was just asking whether it can be done in a simple way (without overloading and such).

Comment: "Without overloading" means you are talking about built-in operators. If so, then what specific operator/type combination are you talking about? I'm not aware of any built-in `+=` operator that would be order-dependent? Your example with string literals makes no sense: you cannot concatenate string litertals using `+=` in C++.

Comment: It sounds like your question wasn't about operators after all, but about the easiest way to prepend to a string?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: You can introduce new operations, but they won't be single-token operators.

Comment: @BenVoigt What operations can you introduce?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Yakk's approach makes it possible to use anything that fits the pattern (operator token)(identifier)(operator token).  The precedence and associativity of the resulting "named operator" are related to the operator tokens used at beginning and end of the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the question isn't so much about defining operators, as it is about inserting one string into another. In that case, `std::string` has a whole bunch of [`insert` member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) for doing that.

Specifically, to insert the string `y` at the front of string `x` you can use `x.insert(0, y);`

Answer (score 1):

By using a helper type, you can make the following work where `x` and `y` are an existing type like `std::string`:

```
x +prefix= y;
```

Credit for this "named operators" approach goes to Yakk, you can find a more complete discussion with implementation examples at https://github.com/klmr/named-operator.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering whether it's possible with a simple solution, I thinks it would be simpler to just do it without shortcut operators. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, create your own type and overload operator `+=`. ie:

```
struct MyString 
{
    std::string _string;

    MyString(const std::string & str) : _string(str) {}
    MyString(std::string && str) : _string(std::move(str)) { }

    void operator+=(const MyString & rhs)
    {
        _string = rhs._string + _string;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyString abc("abc");
    MyString xyz("xyz");

    abc += xyz;

    std::cout << abc._string;
}
```

Comment: I was asking whether it's possible in a simple way, but thanks anyways!